# How to use Grails GORM with BaseX NoSQL?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, basex, nosql

Is Grails Domain class always use GORM?

I want to use [BaseX](http://basex.org/) for my persistent database. Unfortunately, "GORM for BaseX" is not provided by [Grails Plugins](http://plugins.grails.org/).

How to write Domain class without hibernate and use custom NoSQL?

If I must write custom GORM plugin, is any tutorial out there?

Comment: To use GORM and BaseX, you would need to write a GORM implementation. I'm not aware of any tutorials on doing so